# How can I click my radion button with protractor?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have some radiobuttons and I have to click at the first one, but protractor keeps me returning "element not visible". Am I using the selector in a wrong way?

```
I've trying:
element.all(by.css('ui-radiobutton-icon.ui-clickable')).first.click();
```

and

```
element.all(by.class('ui-radiobutton-icon.ui-clickable')).first.click();
```

**HTML**

```
<p-dtradiobutton class="ng-star-inserted">
        <div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">
            <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                <input type="radio">
            </div>
            <div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-radiobutton-relative ui-state-default">
                <span class="ui-radiobutton-icon ui-clickable"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p-dtradiobutton>
```

Comment: Looks like its your selector, maybe try element.all(by.class('.ui-radiobutton-icon .ui-clickable')).first.click();

I don't know protractor but what you had wasn't a valid querySelectory query to find that element.

Comment: why are you using element.all instead of unique locator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no such thing browser.class in protractor. Second thing is 2 mistakes in your code.

Instead of

```
 element.all(by.css('ui-radiobutton-icon.ui-clickable')).first.click();
```

use this code

```
element.all(by.css('.ui-radiobutton-icon.ui-clickable')).first().click();
```

if you it errors out element not clickable or invisible

```
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  var element=element.all(by.css('.ui-radiobutton-icon.ui-clickable')).first();
  var isClickable = EC.elementToBeClickable(element);
  browser.wait(isClickable, 5000);
  element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try below.

element.all(by.css('ui-radiobutton-icon.ui-clickable  input ')).first.click();

Answer (score 0):

You're missing one "." before class ui-radiobutton-icon. Try this:

```
element.all(by.css('.ui-radiobutton-icon.ui-clickable')).first.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Few errors I see:

1) It is `first()` and not `first`

2) `by.class('foo')` should be `by.className('foo')`

3) not sure though, but you probably want to click the `input` element

In general when using locators, you should chain them. Try to begin at the very top of your page and chain it down to the element which should be selected. For reusability, you can also store chained `element` calls. In general, try to use `element()`  instead of `element.all()` if possible.

For clicking the radio button I would suggest following code:

```
// start at the very top.
element(by.tagName('p-dtradiobutton'))  
 .element(by.css('.ui-radioButton .ui-helper-hidden-accessible'))
 .element(by.tagName('input')).click();
```